# CanvasJS change tooltip color from data color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, canvasjs

I am using `canvas.js` and it is working fine. I just want to change the color of the `tooltip`. I try by the following code

```
 toolTip: {
            enabled: true,
            animationEnabled: true,
            fontColor: "red",
            Content: "{x} : {y}",
          },
```

By it not change the whole tooltip color. 
How can I do that.

Here is my JS

```
var chartResponses = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartResponses", {
                animationEnabled: true,
                toolTip: {
                    enabled: true,
                    animationEnabled: true,
                    fontColor: "red",
                    Content: "{x} : {y}",
                    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
                },
                axisX: {
                    titleFontFamily: "verdana",
                    valueFormatString: "D/M/YYYY",
                    tickThickness: 0,
                    lineThickness: 1,
                    gridThickness: 0,
                    gridColor: "#f2f6f7",
                    lineColor: "#f2f6f7",
                    labelFontColor: "#8fa2aa",
                    labelFontSize: 12
                },
                axisY: {
                    titleFontFamily: "verdana",
                    valueFormatString: "0",
                    tickThickness: 0,
                    lineThickness: 0,
                    gridThickness: 1,
                    gridColor: "#f2f6f7",
                    lineColor: "#f2f6f7",
                    labelFontColor: "#8fa2aa",
                    labelFontSize: 12
                },
                data: [{
                        type: "splineArea",
                        showInLegend: true,
                        markerSize: 0,
                        name: "",
                        color: "rgba(29, 176, 237, 0.25)",
                        dataPoints: allResponses
                    }],
            });

    chartResponses.render();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set backgroundColor of toolTip to change it's background color.

```
var  chart =  new  CanvasJS.Chart("container",
{
 .
 .
 toolTip:{
  backgroundColor: "#f4d5a6",
 },
 .
 .
});
chart.render();
```

Please refer the [documentation](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/tooltip/background-color/).

Comment: I want to change the color of tooltip not the background color.

Comment: Can you please share any image of your requirement, so that we can look into it and provide a solution

Comment: I want the date which you can check in the image tooltip `7/7/2016 :20` to be in different color from the graph data field. like `20` is in different color right now.

Answer (score 0):

Using [fontColor](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/tooltip/font-color/) property, you can customize the font-color of toolTip.

[image: toolTip-fontColor]

Here is your code and the result.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  toolTip: {
    enabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    fontColor: "red",
    Content: "{x} : {y}",
    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
  },
  axisX: {
    titleFontFamily: "verdana",
    valueFormatString: "D/M/YYYY",
    tickThickness: 0,
    lineThickness: 1,
    gridThickness: 0,
    gridColor: "#f2f6f7",
    lineColor: "#f2f6f7",
    labelFontColor: "#8fa2aa",
    labelFontSize: 12
  },
  axisY: {
    titleFontFamily: "verdana",
    valueFormatString: "0",
    tickThickness: 0,
    lineThickness: 0,
    gridThickness: 1,
    gridColor: "#f2f6f7",
    lineColor: "#f2f6f7",
    labelFontColor: "#8fa2aa",
    labelFontSize: 12
  },
  data: [{
    type: "splineArea",
    showInLegend: true,
    markerSize: 0,
    name: "",
    color: "rgba(29, 176, 237, 0.25)",
    dataPoints: [
      { x: new Date(2016,08,01), y: 40 },
      { x: new Date(2016,08,02), y: 30 },
      { x: new Date(2016,08,03), y: 60 },
      { x: new Date(2016,08,04), y: 80 },
      { x: new Date(2016,08,05), y: 50 },
      { x: new Date(2016,08,06), y: 90 },
      { x: new Date(2016,08,07), y: 30 },
      { x: new Date(2016,08,08), y: 40 },
      { x: new Date(2016,08,09), y: 70 }
    ]
  }]
});
chart.render();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 260px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: As you can check in my code I am using properties but it is not reflecting. `Data(7/7/2016)` is using data color while `20` is using the color which I provided by tooltip `fontColor: "red",`. 

Is there any thing wrong in the code?

Comment: I have taken your code itself and its working fine. Can you create a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/QwZuf/)  with your issue, so that we can understand the issue in your case and help you out.